# What is the best way to verify users with special access

Tags: mongodb, jwt, bcrypt

I have a MERN stack app and I need to check for admin access, when any user logs in, they are given a cookie using jwt after their password has been checked using bcrypt.

What is the best way to securely verify if a user has admin permissions though? Should I add a 'isAdmin': true property to the 'user' model in mongodb and then check for this everytime they need admin privileges to access the content or do I need to do something more secure? If so, what would be the best option?

Comment: You can think of assigning role to users and permissions to roles, that is basically how it works in many apps. So you can add a role property to the user model and create a static model for assigning permissions to roles. When a user logs in check his role and load the corresponding permissions on the backend (keep it loaded in memory for fast lookup), then when necessary check if the user has the permission to do something.

Comment: Thank you, is this safe? Is there a way a user could change their role in anyway?

Comment: It will depend on your implementation, google `role based access control node` you will find what you need.